# React useContext returns default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to create a darkmode library (named react-goodnight) based on https://github.com/luisgserrano/react-dark-mode.

This is where the context is created.

```jsx
import React from 'react'

const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: '',
  toggle: () => {}
})

export default ThemeContext
```

This is my useDarkMode hook that get/sets the theme to localStorage.

```jsx
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useDarkMode = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light')

  const setMode = (mode) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', mode)
    setTheme(mode)
  }

  const toggle = () => (theme === 'light' ? setMode('dark') : setMode('light'))

  useEffect(() => {
    const localTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme')
    localTheme && setTheme(localTheme)
  }, [])

  return [theme, toggle]
}

export default useDarkMode
```

This is the index of my library (react-goodnight).

```jsx
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'

import { GlobalStyles } from './globalStyles'

import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from './settings'

import ThemeContext from './themeContext'

import useDarkMode from './useDarkMode'

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, toggle] = useDarkMode()

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme === 'light' ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggle }}>
        <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
        {children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export const useDarkModeContext = () => useContext(ThemeContext)
export default Provider
```

And, in the end, this is my example app where I'm trying to use it.

```jsx
import React from 'react'

import Provider, { useDarkModeContext } from 'react-goodnight'

const App = () => {
  const { theme, toggle } = useDarkModeContext();

  console.log(theme)
  return (
    <Provider>
      <div>hey</div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

The "Toggle" button in the library's index works fine but the one in my example app does not.
The useDarkModeContext() returns empty.

What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong

**1st option**

you can use `react-goodnight` provider with your index.js and use `useDarkModeContext()`, don't name your index.js `Provider` else you can not use `Provider` coming from `react-goodnight`

```
import Provider, { useDarkModeContext } from 'react-goodnight'

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, toggle] = useDarkMode()

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme === 'light' ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Provider>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggle }}>
          <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
          {children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      </Provider>  
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

**2nd Option**

you are passing `ThemeContext` in your `index.js` so you can also access that in `app.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import ThemeContext from './themeContext'


const App = () => {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.log(theme)
  return (
    <Provider>
      <div>hey</div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, but I'm actually building react-goodnight. So, index (Provider) is react-goodnight's.

Comment: ohh I didnt see it, can you please make snippet so I solve it asap

Comment: please make the snippet so I can solve this fastly, you can use codesandbox for snippet

Comment: Check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-glitter-lolnr

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-ganguly-8y7vk?file=/src/app.js, you did reverse methodology, calling index from the app so you can not rerender it

Comment: Hi, sorry but this is not the design I need. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you are calling **useContext** in the very same place where you print **Provider**.

Why is that wrong? Because **useContext** looks for **parent** context providers. By rendering **Provider** in the same place you call **useContext**, there is no parent to look for. The **useContext** in your example is actually part of **App** component, who **is not a child** of **Provider.**

All you have to do is move the button outside of that print, to its own component, and only there do **useContext** (or in your case the method called **useDarkModeContext**.

The only change would be:

```
import React from 'react'
import Provider, { useDarkModeContext } from 'react-goodnight'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <div>hey</div>
      <ToggleThemeButton />
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App

const ToggleThemeButton = () => {
  const { theme, toggle } = useDarkModeContext();
  return (
    <button onClick={toggle}>Switch Theme outside</button>
  );

};
```